# How to group according to a field value

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I got result after executing linq query in mvc like below:

```
[0] = { albumid = 176, selecttionid = 243, orderid = 57 }
[1] = { albumid = 177, selecttionid = 243, orderid = 57 }
[2] = { albumid = 178, selecttionid = 243, orderid = 57 }

[3] = { albumid = 19, selecttionid = 321, orderid = 137 }
```

......

But I need to create folder for each different selecttionid .How can I do this?

Comment: Use `GroupBy` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to create a folder for each diferente **selecttionid**, than you just need use Select with Distinct, like that:

```
var selections = mylist.Select(x => x.selecttionid).Distinct();
foreach(var selection in selections)
{
    //Code that create a folder for the selectionId
}
```

If you need the values from the list, than you can use GroupBy.

```
var groupedSelections = mylist.GroupBy(x => x.selecttionid);
foreach(var groupSelecion in groupedSelections)
{
    //Code that create a folder for the groupSelecion.Key
}
```